# How to remove "padding" from ionic card

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to insert inamges inside ionic cards. I preferred to use cards because I want to keep aspect homogeneous. The problem is that, as you can see on the next image, there is a white space at the bottom (more evident here, but also present at top and sides) of the card after an image:

[image: You can see the bottom padding-like space]

I have tried using CSS but no luck. In part it is probably because I don't know which CSS is involved. Also, I don't really know how to remove such white space.. I even tried using negative padding values but it does not work so I suppose it is not really the card component but a subpart which is doing the issue.

This is my current code:

```
<div class="card" ng-controller="cycleImagesCtrl">
    <div class="item item-body" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
        <img src={{imgTitle}} width="100%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **1st** you should never assign **negative values** to `padding` as it won't work. If you need to work with **negative values** then use `margin`,

**2nd** try adding `width` and `height` of `100%` to your `img`.

Just for example -

```css
#parent{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
}

#parent > img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I added 100% both to high and width with no change. It seems just adding for width does work equally as the card is vertically resized to fit the image proportions.

Comment: @kankamuso in your above img tag add min-height:100% too and try, or create a working example of your code.

Comment: Hey, I have just tried the margin you suggested and, in combination with padding 0px it does work. Now it is like this <div class="item item-body" style="margin-bottom: -5px;padding: 0px">. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome @kankamuso and well that's great that it worked out by assigning negative value to margin :-)

Answer (score 5):

Add `margin: 0 !important;` and `padding: 0 !important;` for your card's css. Like this:

```
ion-card {
width:100%;
height:300px;
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}

ion-card > img {
 width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

<ion-card>
<img src="...">
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'no-padding' attribute, https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities
Or the new (since the attribute is deprecated) 'class="no-padding'

```
<ion-card class='no-padding'>
  <ion-card-header class='no-padding'>
    <img src='...' />
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content class='no-padding'>
    Some content
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: In the meantime it's been changed to `ion-no-padding`, see https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#content-space

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic v5, Following worked for me,
I used `<ion-img>` tag to render images and I set `class="no-padding card-background-page"` to `<ion-content>` tag.

**Code:**

```html
<ion-content class="no-padding card-background-page">
    <ion-card>
        <ion-img src="assets/img/yourimg.jpg"></ion-img>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out the solution. I am using Ionic 5.

```
ion-card { font-size: 0; }
```